# Why didn't Iran declare war on the United States for shooting down flight-655?

Tags: war, aircraft

In 1988, an American warship captain fired a missile on an Iranian civilian Airbus killing all 290 civilians onboard. From this [documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPHGUQrixWc&ab_channel=Wonder), it looks like the captain who was already exposed to Iranian hostilities firing on them from gun boats was caught in a judgment call on whether to fire on the aircraft or not because all communications they had tried to establish with the airline failed. The computer which had the information on the movement showed that this aircraft was maintaining its vertical altitude and was not trying to suicide bomb into the American warship. When the Iranian aircraft had reached a proximity of less than 10 miles from the American warship, the captain who seemed to bulge more toward pressure directed to him from colleagues instead of the data being indicated on the computer  decided to fire on the Airbus while placing his finger on the `Hold Fire` button in case the airline replied which never happened so all lives on the craft were tragically ended.

If this event happened in a world war two environmment, then this could have meant total war between Iran and the United States, why did Iran not declare war on the US?

Comment: Iran had been in a war of attrition with Iraq for eight years and was in no way capable of conducting anything but a losing war with the U.S. at that point.

Comment: Could this have caused 9/11 indirectly or at least have contributed?

Comment: @Mathew: Iran had nothing to do with 9/11. Their form of Shia Islam is anathema to Al-Quaeda's militant Sunni Islam.

Comment: I would say the same for Saudi Arabia

Comment: @Mathew: AQ's militant Sunni is far more compatible with Saudi Wahhabism. AQ's primary problem with Saudi Arabia was that the government was corrupt, unrepresentative and un-Islamic, and they weren't wrong about those things. That's why so many AQ members - including 15 out of 19 of the 9/11 hijackers - were from Saudi.

Comment: I just wonder how scared the government of Iran is to stand up fo atrocities committed againsts its citizens to the point of not asking for reparations to compensate the families for such a tragedy, if they did arbitrate peacefully with the U.S gov

Comment: This seems to be more informed by rhetoric and politics than history.  It is difficult to use historical sources and methods to discuss "Why not" or "why didn't".  What would have been Iran's strategic and operational goals in declaring war? Does Iran have the capacity to deploy military forces far from it's operating theater?  Is Iran better served by asymmetrical warfare than military conflict?

Comment: The US did not declare war in 1937 when the Japanese sank the USS Panay in a deliberate attack against a well marked US warship.  And the why?  At the top of the list, just like the Iranians, they, the US, was in no way capable of entering into a war with a foreign power at the time.   One has to decide just what is worth a war and its consequences and what is not.

Comment: And, likewise, what is worth a war and its consequences and what is not, the same reason the South Koreans did not declare war on the Soviet Union in 1983 when a Soviet Air Force fighter shot down the KAL 007 airliner with the loss of 269 souls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Iranian government is not actually crazy. Strange, yes. Suicidal, no.

If they had declared war on the USA they would expect to be defeated, their regime overthrown, and the country to be ruled by the US. They really didn't want that, so they did not declare war.

In a WWII context, an analogous position might be the likes of Columbia or Peru deciding to join the Axis in spring 1940, and declaring war on the US at that point. That's obviously silly, isn't it?

The US eventually [paid compensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Air_Flight_655#Aftermath) to the victims' families:

> US$61.8 million of the claim was in compensation for the 248 Iranians killed in the shoot-down: $300,000 per wage-earning victim and $150,000 per non-wage-earner.
>
> The U.S. government issued notes of regret for the loss of human lives, but never formally apologized or acknowledged wrongdoing.

Comment: I want to believe the US government was forced into compensating the families that lost their loved ones through this in the form of reparations or something, otherwise this is catastrophic.

Comment: Your answer would be so much different if the airline was Russian or Chinese

Comment: @Mathew: Compensation was eventually paid, see the edited answer.

Comment: ***but never formally apologized or acknowledged wrongdoing***, understandable given the situation, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: An error, no matter how grevious, is never wrongdoing. The negligence of creating the situation where the error was more likely might be wrongdoing, but now you're well into needing deep intellectual analysis of facts and history and balancing many conflicting needs before you can judge rightly. This is one reason (there are others of course) why governments are more likely to express regret rather than apologize.

Comment: Have you looked at a map and seen a) how *large* Iran is and b) who was Iran's northern neighbour in 1988? The US did not even manage to really rule Iraq after 2003, despite Iraq being a much smaller country and much less interesting for Russia. Agree that fighting a war against the US would have been unwise, but not with your what-if scenario.

Comment: I think this answer probably overstates things a fair bit, but its certainly true that Iran had 0 ability to prosecute an intercontinental war via any means save [asymmetric warfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_warfare) (which doesn't require any declaration of war, and they arguably [were already engaging in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_and_state-sponsored_terrorism#Hezbollah))